# How to drag the iphoneX simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-x

When moving the iPhoneX simulator I have tried *clicking and dragging* at the **top, bottom and both sides and even all the corners** but sometimes it works and other times it does not.

Why is this so random?

Where is there best place to click seeing as though there is no discernible bar like in other Mac applications

Putting this question up because it has been frustrating me for ages and maybe it will alleviate someone else's stress out there in dev-land.

Comment: You're awesome for this. It was pretty annoying for years. I cannot believe I did not look this up sooner. I always blamed it on my machine. Not realizing it makes perfect sense that it behaves this way. Because the swipe from the corner gesture is the expected behavior on a real device.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

So *trick question* actually because you can click and drag from anywhere, **BUT** the trick is **dragging** in the direction **away from the simulator** first then you can drag it wherever you like.

The problem here is when you click and drag towards the screen first it gets picked up as a swipe event. Thats what you want to avoid.

**WRONG**

[image: wrong way]

**RIGHT**

[image]

Comment: You can also click and drag the name below the simulator window.

Comment: Yes exactly, top bottom right left... all good. So long as you drag away from the simulator.

Comment: Using the area below the simulator where the name of it is displayed seems to work pretty consistently. Drag away from the simulator first: no go for me. Why is this such a PITA?

Comment: C'mon Apple. Why this?

Comment: @Robert It's obviously mentioned that's to avoid swipe gesture triggered first, which is just like when you're using physical iPhone X.

Answer (score 13):

If, like me, you can't get the accepted answer to work, choose the `Window` > `Show Device Bezels` menu item. The virtual device will get a normal window title bar which you can drag around.

Comment: Valid answer in 2020